# Passing Object References and Concurrency / JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency

I am creating a window with JavaFX, using an object oriented approach which will allow different kinds of windows to be created with the same basic framework.  These windows will display html content.

I have run into a concurrency problem when trying to add an observer.

Window:

```
public Window(String linkName, String fName, String wName, int width, int height, GuiObserver o) throws IOException {
    wApp = new WindowApp();
    wApp.setObserver(o);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            wApp.launch(WindowApp.class,linkName,fName,wName,""+width,""+height);
            /*try {
                wApp.launch(WindowApp.class,linkName,fName,wName,""+width,""+height);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
        }
    }).start();
}
```

This creates the window and sets the observer, but puts the launch into a new thread.  I can confirm that the observer is added, but the observer cannot be notified.  Here is the WindowApp class:

```
/**
 * Instantiate the class with an html file
 * THIS MUST NOT TAKE ANY PARAMETERS
 */
public WindowApp() throws IOException {}

@Override
public void start(Stage s) throws Exception {

    this.stage = s;

    //get the parameters
    List<String> params = getParameters().getRaw();
    String linkName = params.get(0);
    updateHtmlFromFile(new File(params.get(1)));
    windowName = params.get(2);
    windowWidth = Integer.parseInt(params.get(3));
    windowHeight = Integer.parseInt(params.get(4));

    //create the window
    stage.setWidth(windowWidth);
    stage.setHeight(windowHeight);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());


    browser = new WebView();
    webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //add the link which will bind Java and Javascript functionality
    Class jC = Class.forName(linkName);
    Constructor jCon = jC.getConstructor(browser.getClass(),webEngine.getClass(),stage.getClass());
    javascriptLink = (JavascriptLink) jCon.newInstance(browser,webEngine,stage);
    javascriptLink.setObserver(gObserver);

    //javascriptLink = new JavascriptLink(browser,webEngine,stage);

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setContent(browser);

    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
        .addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {

            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
              stage.setTitle(windowName);
            }

          }
        });
    webEngine.load(htmlUrl);

    scene.setRoot(scrollPane);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
    /**
     * Add an observer to the javascript Link
     * @param o
     */
    public void setObserver(GuiObserver o) {
        gObserver = o;
    }
```

This object also has a "Javascript link" which interacts with the HTML document after its launch:

```
package gui;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainWindowJSLink extends JavascriptLink {

    private GuiObserver gObserver;

    /**
     * This will be called by WindowApp when appropriate, and does not need to be called by a person
     * @param b
     * @param we
     * @param st
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    public MainWindowJSLink(WebView b, WebEngine we, Stage st) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(b, we, st);
    }

    @Override
    public void eventTriggered(String eventName) {
        System.out.println("Event triggered -> "+eventName);

        switch (eventName) {
            case "codeEditorContentsChanged":
                handleCodeEditorContentsChanged();
                break;
        }

        //notify observers if necessary
        this.triggerObserver(eventName, null);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event that the contents of the code editor have changed
     * This will probably setup a timer to wait a few seconds until the user has stopped typing,
     *      then send the contents to the syntax highlighter and get the result back  
     */
    private void handleCodeEditorContentsChanged() {
        //System.out.println(getJSCodeEditorContents());
    }

    /**
     * Get the raw contents of the code editor (unedited and not stripped of html entities)
     * @return
     */
    public String getJSCodeEditorContents() {
        String contents = (String) super.webEngine.executeScript("getCodeEditorContents()");

        return contents;
    }

    /**
     * Set the contents of the code editor
     * @param contents String
     * NOTE: 
     */
    public void setJSCodeEditorContents(String contents) {
        super.webEngine.executeScript("setCodeEditorContents(`"+contents+"`)");
    }

    //observer observable stuff
    @Override
    public void setObserver(GuiObserver o) {
        gObserver = o;
        gObserver.setJS(this);
        System.out.println("MainWindow -> observer set");
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerObserver(String s, Object o) {
        gObserver.trigger(s,o);
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Handle information sent from the 
     */
    public void send(String s, Object o) {
        //handle information sent to this object
}
    }
```

Unfortunately, the gObserver.trigger does not execute.  Interestingly enough, if I put a System.exit(0) before that trigger is called, the program exits.  However, if I put it after it is called (or in the corresponding method), it is not.

Can anyone offer any advice on how to fix this concurrency issue?  If you need more information, please let me know, and I will provide it.

Comment: I think your understanding of the flow is incorrect.   wApp.launch(WindowApp.class,linkName,fName,wName,""+width,""+height); will create a new instance of WindowApp - will not use the one you instantiated before this call was made.

Comment: You should only have one `Application` subclass in your application, and you should never instantiate it yourself - it will be instantiated when you call `launch()`. Also note that it is only allowed to call `launch()` once (per JVM). Your `Application` class really should do nothing at all except manage the lifecycle of the entire application (the entire JVM process, so to speak).

Comment: For 1st comment: I see, in that case, will wApp.launch() return the handle for the instance created there?

Comment: For 2nd comment, the idea of my approach was to be able to create (launch) multiple windows in new threads if necessary (one for main window, one for settings, etc).  Are you saying that I cannot do that because of the restrictions on launch() ?

Comment: You can, of course, create as many windows as you like. You **must** create them all on the same thread (specifically, the FX Application Thread), but that should not be a restriction. You can only call `launch()` once, but that has nothing to do with creating new windows.

Comment: "Will `Application.launch()` return a [reference to] the instance created?"  No. And it doesn't return until the application exits anyway; it would be pretty much useless at that point.

Comment: Ok, so really, I should make a simple class to "launch" once only, then from what is launched, I can create many windows and handle everything, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Also, one more question, how would I create a new window without using launch()?  It seems to me that if I can do that, I can create a window without using launch() at all.

Comment: You create a new window the same way you create anything else in Java: `Stage anotherWindow = new Stage();`. But you need the JavaFX toolkit to be running, and you need to create the window on the FX Application Thread. If you don't call `launch()`, the toolkit won't be running (there are other ways in Java 9, but there is really no need to do anything unusual or unexpected in this use case). So follow the usual pattern: your `main()` method calls `launch()` (and does nothing else), your `start()` method is the entry point for the application, where you do the startup.